# Fork to shell script and terminate original process with Haskell

Tags: haskell, process, fork

I am currently writing a Haskell program that does some initialization work and then calls ncmpcpp. What I am trying to do is start ncmpcpp and terminate the Haskell program, so that only ncmpcpp is left (optionally, the program can keep running in the background, as long as it's unintrusive)

However, even though I am able to start ncmpcpp, I cannot interact with it. I see its output, but input appears to be impossible.

What I am currently doing is:

```
import System.Process (createProcess, proc)
...
spawnCurses :: [String] -> IO ()
spawnCurses params = do 
  _ <- createProcess (proc "ncmpcpp" params)
  return ()
```

What am I doing wrong/What should I do differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve sounds like what the [`exec`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exec_%28operating_system%29) family of functions does. Take a look at the [`executeFile`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=executeFile) function.

If you want your parent Haskell process to be still running after the child process is started read about [fork-exec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork-exec) and the [`forkProcess`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=forkProcess) function.

A complete example of using `forkProcess` together with `executeFile` can be found at http://therning.org/magnus/archives/727.

Comment: The link to Magnus's site is dead. It must be [somewhere here](https://magnus.therning.org/archive.html) now. Probably [this post](https://magnus.therning.org/posts/2009-08-21-727-forkexec-in-haskell.html).